# No internet on Windows 10 Notebook

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, lan, internet-connection

I am using a Dell Precision 5550 with Windows 10 21H1 Build 19043.1237

I don't have an internet connection. Lan is plugged in and lan name is shown but windows states "No Internet". Same for WiFi. I can connect, but "No Internet, secured".

I tried following commands which didn't help:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns

netsh int ip reset
netsh winsock reset

netcfg -d
```

Misc things that didn't work:

- Pinging google.com or 8.8.8.8 results in "general failure"
- Also, pinging a peer or being pinged in my own network results in
  "general failure"
- DNS Settings are set to auto in Control Panel + no DNS resolution
  via nslookup
- Nothing suspicious in Route Table.
- Restarted Lan and WiFi Adapters
- Reinstalled Ethernet Driver

Comment: Try updating / reinstalling drivers for both network cards

Comment: @John May I ask how I should update/ reinstall drivers when I am offline? Someone told me something about a MS tool for that but I cant seem to find it.

Comment: When you are online on a different computer, download the appropriate drivers from the Dell Support site, put them on a USB key and update that way.

Comment: Is it just the *internet* that's not available, though you have access to the local LAN? That can be be caused by DNS issues. Set DNS lookup, both IPv4 and IPv6, to auto, if they're not.

Comment: Does the LAN have internet access. Internet access is different to being connected, which you are. Ditto for the WiFi. If they are both the same router then check that the router is connected to the internet. Or explain your network configuration..